# How to generate a list with elements f[i] for a function of several variables f?

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to create an array of length n with each element i equal to the function

```
σEk[j_, k_, n_] := 
 Insert[ConstantArray[IdentityMatrix[2], n - 1], PauliMatrix[j], k ]
```

evaluated at `k=i`, i.e.

```
σEklist[j_, n_] := {σEk[j, 1, n], σEk[j, 2, n], ..., σEk[j, n, n]}
```

I tried using the Mathematica function for one-variable functions, `Array[f,n] = {f[i], ..., f[n]}`, using:

```
σEklist[j_, n_] := Array[σEk, n]
```

and I also tried to define `σEk[j, k, n]` as a function of the variable `k` only within the function `σEklist[j_, n_]` using `Module`, i.e.

```
σEklist[j_, n_] := 
 Module[{f[k_] := σEk[j, k, n]}, Array[f, n]]
```

but in each case the function `σEklist[j_, n_]` doesn't read the `n` and `j` variables in the function `σEk[j, k, n]` as being its own variables.

Any help or tips would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Like this `σEklist[j_, n_] := Array[σEk[j,#,n]&, n]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

σEk[j_Integer?(0 <= # <= 4 &), k_Integer?Positive, 
  n_Integer?Positive] :=
 Insert[ConstantArray[IdentityMatrix[2], n - 1], PauliMatrix[j], k]

σEklist[j_Integer?(0 <= # <= 4 &), 
  n_Integer?Positive] := σEk[j, #, n] & /@ Range[n]
```

or

```
σEklist2[j_Integer?(0 <= # <= 4 &), n_Integer?Positive] :=
 Array[σEk[j, #, n] &, n]
```

`σEklist` and `σEklist2` are equivalent

```
And @@ (Table[σEklist[j, n] == σEklist2[j, n], {j, 0, 4}, {n, 1,
      5}] // Flatten)

(* True *)
```